# How to delete a model instance and modify the user profile when another model instance is created?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm devoleping a website where you can see different matches and vote for the team you think that will win.

When the match ends, I would like to create an instance in the `django` admin with the match and the winner of the match, delete all the votes and add points to every user that voted for the winning team.

These are my models:

```
class Prognostic(models.Model):
    match = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.IntegerField()
    vote = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vote


class MatchResult(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey("MatchOpponents")
    winner = models.ForeignKey("TeamGGC")

    @receiver(post_save, sender=Prognostic)
    def voteRepartitionPoints(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        profil = apps.get_model("userMembers", "Profil")
        for prognostic in Prognostic().object.filter(match = match_id):
            if prognostic.vote == winner:
                user = profil.object.get(user_id = prog.user)
                user.nbGGCPoints += 50
                user.save()
            prognostic.delete()

    def __int__(self):
        return self.match
```

But when I do that, nothing happens. What is required to get this to work?

Comment: Please, fix indentation of your pasted code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoc can create a **vote model** and then proceed.

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    value = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    match = models.ForeignKey("MatchOpponents")

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'match'),)
```

Comment: I have to create a vote model in extra of the two precedents models ?
And it's possible to do what i was trying?
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @MagiPrince No you dont need to create an extra model, you can replace your first model Prognostic with vote model.

Comment: I try the code you propose to me, but actually this didn't work because i fill the vote model with post data from my template. Do you think it's possible to do what i'm trying in with an admin function ?

Comment: @You need to work on considering this model, but you need to make a lot of changes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I make a lot of changes in my code and now it works! :)